US Immigrant Visa - Asked to send in passport but I already submitted passport "Administrative Processing"
I applied for an immigrant visa and went through the interview, I gave them documents that they requested, after the interview was over, visa officer said my visa is denied and handed over white letter but they kept passport. In that letter it was said that there were no visas available for this category and temprorarily suspend processing my visa application.
And after a few weeks I got message saying "The U.S. Consulate in Mumbai requests that you submit your passport"
But, I already submitted my passport at the time of the interview and they never gave back. I thought they were asking my expired passport but at the counter they didn't took saying that they don't need expired passport.
How can I give my passport when I already gave them? Does anyone have any idea what to do situation like this? Any experience regarding this would be helpful.

Nobody is going to be able to help you here other than the consulate themselves.  What did they say when you asked them?

When I checked with the counter and showed him the letter, he said to wait and checked with his manager and told me to send an email (usdocs) and see what they have to say and come back later.
But my request was kept on hold and has been escalated. Although I saw few people happen like this, but I didn't see any resoluton as of how it is solved from customers end.
